# AIX 6.1 server, when too many jobs are running, it can take up to 20 seconds to return simple kernel commands, but other stuff doesn't slow down

Tags: kernel, aix

oslevel command is what we're using to measure this, i just run it in a loop and spit out the time it took to complete, normally it's .25s, but when we run a bunch of shell scripts that do simple file io stuff, it slows down to 20 seconds per run...

This has got to be a recognizable symptom of a specific problem, like a bottleneck in "blah blah blah kernel blah blah" ... but I'm not seeing helpful results from googling around...

notice: the file i/o it's self doesn't slow down, and the drives (iostat 1) are not at 100% useage, they fluctuate up and down btw 100% and 0%, but it's not like we're io blocked or something...

The box has drastically more memory and cpu capacity than we're using, so we're stuck throttling ourselves to a piddling ammt of cpu/memory/io usage, because of this kernel bottleneck...

any ideas?

Comment: very few aix people here on S.O. Better to register at http://ittoolbox.com and join the AIX group. There are also IBM supported forums for aix, and I would expect that with a service contract you'd be entitled to help with this issue (but that is my very limited experience from 5 yrs ago). Good luck!

Comment: If you want to know what '/usr/bin/oslevel' actually does, just read it -- it is a shell script

Answer (score 0):

Is it observed only when oslevel command is run ? or any other commands as well ?. 
oslevel is a shell script, I can see internally it has loops in some part of the code, also it checks for available freespace in the filesystem, as you said you are running this command with some simple file io jobs, are those jobs try to empty the free space in the filesystems ?, then it might be expected your jobs might be impacting the oslevel command. Also When you observed the performance is not impacted for your jobs but only for commands like oslevel, then it has to be problem with the specific command that is running. May not be a kernel bug in my opinion.